# How to tell AutoMapper not to map object graph entirely

Tags: automapper

I have a series of classes that have relations to each others. Like:

```
public class Patient : Entity
{
    public virtual string FirstName { set; get; }
    public virtual OfficeBranch OriginalOfficeBranch { set; get; }
}

public class OfficeBranch : Entity
{
    public virtual string Title { set; get; }
}
```

And DTOs:

```
public class PatientDto : BaseGeneralDto
{
    public string FirstName { set; get; }
    public OfficeBranchDto OriginalOfficeBranch { set; get; }
}

public class OfficeBranchDto : BaseGeneralDto
{
    public string Title { set; get; }
}
```

I have used `AutoMapper` to map them to each other. I'm using `NHibernate` for persisting. When updating `PatientDto`, `AutoMapper` causes to changes in `OfficeBranchDto` too so a `NHibernate` dirty session Flush occurs that is absolutely unwanted.

What I want to know is how can tell `AutoMapper` not to map object graph entirely. I mean just map `PatientDto` to `Patient` not both `PatientDto` and `OfficeBranchDto`. The workaround currently I use is to add Ignore for each mapping manually like:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<PatientDto, Patient>().ForMember(m => m.OriginalOfficeBranch, i => i.Ignore());
```

But I guess there is a better solution.

Comment: As a hint: DTOs are likely to be Data Transfer-er Objects. Naturally they must not be participated in CRUD operations. You may mark your DTOs mutable objects in hibernate mapping file. some thing like: <class name="PatientDto" table="TABLE_NAME"  mutable="false">

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring members you don't want to map is done via Ignore(). There's no better solution - how is AutoMapper supposed to guess what you want to map and don't want to map? It can't, so you have to be explicit.

Comment: If I draw each class as a circle and link them with a line based on referencing each other, It would seen as a graph. What I need is to tell `AutoMapper` not to traverse among this graph. In other hand I want to just map integral types like int, string, double and enums. Hope had clarified the problem.